# Is the setuptools package or setup.py used for anything other than installing? like for finding a module to import in a package?

Tags: python, installation, setuptools

I got the following warning when I was trying to run a ros launch file. I was not installing any packages. Just running a few .py files. So why did python give setuptools related warning. I know about the warning and what to do. I just wanna know if setuptools is being used for any purpose here or did python simply gave that warning:

You are running Setup-tools on Python 2, which is no longer
supported and
SETUPTOOLS WILL STOP WORKING
in a subsequent release (no sooner than 2020-04-20).
Please ensure you are installing
Setuptools using pip 9.x or later or pin to `setuptools<45`
in your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected, as Python 2 is EOL, and so a number of libraries have taken it upon themselves to warn their users about that.
ROS is dependent on many libraries and check their versions. They sometimes give warnings to promote user to upgrade.

In this case it's setuptools. But you can run into the same thing with others.

**When I did on my different system, I didn't received this ?**
It could be that a version of certain dependencies which start printing these warnings hasn't been installed on the system on which you did not see the error.

In any case: ROS Noetic will no longer support/require Python 2 -- it'll exclusively depend on Python 3.

You will not see those warnings any more then.

Comment: So, is it a warning thrown by setuptools or ROS? if it is setuptools, why is that library even loaded when im not installing any package

Comment: You are getting warning everytime or one time?

Comment: everytime I run a node or launch file